# What does $:<< "." do to Ruby's require path?

Tags: ruby, require

I don't understand the meaning of `$:<< "."` in Ruby.

I upgraded Ruby to 1.9.1, but a program was not working. My classmate told me that I am supposed to add `$:<< "."`

What does `$:<< "."` do?

Comment: It is important to understand WHY Ruby no longer includes "`.`" in the search path. An exploit on an app could occur by someone being able to drop a file with the name of a required file into your "`.`" directory. The pre-1.9 behavior would load that file, overwriting the behavior of the required file, and would run with the permissions of the application's owner. That could be catastrophic. The default `require` behavior was changed, but `require_relative` was added to allow you to load from the directories relative to your script. I never use `$:<< '.'` but instead explicitly list the path.

Comment: Note that, if the goal of that line is to allow yourself to `require` files in the same directory as the current script, that's not *quite* what you want: it will not behave properly unless the script is in the current working directory. To add the script's directory to the load path, use `$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)` (I use `unshift` to *prepend* the directory to the list, so that it takes precedence over any other load paths there may be.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. `$:` is the variable that holds an array of paths that make up your Ruby's load path
2. `<<` appends an item to the end of the array
3. `.` refers to the current directory

   ```
   1   2  3
   |   |  |
   V   V  V
   $: << "."
   ```

So you are adding the current directory to Ruby's load path

**References:**

1. Can be found in the `Execution Environment Variables` section of of this page from [The Pragmatic Programmers Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html)

   > An array of strings, where each string specifies a directory to be searched for Ruby scripts and binary extensions used by the load and require methods. The initial value is the value of the arguments passed via the -I command-line option, followed by an installation-defined standard library location, followed by the current directory (“.”)[Obviously this link is for an older version of Ruby as this is still in there]. This variable may be set from within a program to alter the default search path; typically, programs use $: << dir to append dir to the path.
2. Can be found in the [docs for array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) at ruby-doc.org.

   > Append—Pushes the given object on to the end of this array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 1.9, Ruby doesn't look for required files in the current working directory AKA `.`. The `$LOAD_PATH` or `$:` global variable is an array of paths where Ruby looks for files you `require`.

By adding `$:<< "."` to your files, you are actually telling Ruby to include your current directory in the search paths. That overrides new Ruby behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you add working directory (`"."`) to ruby load path (`$:`).

Working directory (`"."`) was removed from load path (global variable `$:` or `$-I` or `$LOAD_PATH`) in Ruby 1.9 because it was considered a security risk:

- Your working directory may be any folder, and your script will require files from this folder if these files have appropriate names. For example you have 2 files in Project1 folder main.rb and init.rb:

> ==Project1/main1.rb:
>   $: << "."
>   require 'init'
>   ==Project1/init.rb:
>   puts 'init 1'

And you have alike project:

> ==Project2/main2.rb:
>   $: << "."
>   require 'init'
>   ==Project2/init.rb:
>   puts 'init 2'

If you run Project1 from Project2 folder, then main1.rb will require Project2/init.rb, not Project1/init.rb:

> ~/Projects/Project2$ ruby ../Project1/main1.rb
>   init 2 # may be unexpected an dangerous
>   ~/Projects/Project2$ ruby main2.rb
>   init 2

- You can change your working directory in your code, e.g. using `Dir.chdir`:

  ```
  ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > puts File.expand_path('.')
  => /home/alex/Projects
  ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > Dir.chdir('..') 
  ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > puts File.expand_path('.')
  => /home/alex
  ```

I recommend you to use the following techniques instead of `$: << '.'`:

- [require_relative](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html#M000039) (*Ruby 1.9 only*)
- Add folder of the file to the working directory (common approach because it is compatible with *Ruby 1.8*): `$: << File.expand_path('..', __FILE__) etc.`. `__FILE__` is a reference to the current file name. [File.expand_path](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path) converts a pathname to an absolute pathname.