# How to override require in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to override `require` from within a Ruby file, which is required from my start.rb, which is the application entry point. `rubygems` is loaded before this, in start.rb.

Everything I tried gave me a stack overflow error.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this? Why do you need it?

Comment: There is no right way to do this. You shouldn't.

Comment: Rubygems does it, why I shouldn't?

Comment: There is a lot of code, which I do not want to manually edit. I just need to rewrite require pathes in some cases

Comment: The right way to do it is to start by showing what you've written. It's a lot easier for us to correct a problem than it is to write an entire solution from scratch.

Comment: @guai If you want to rewrite paths, you'll interfere with both RubyGems and Bundler. I suggest that you alter `$:` instead to change the search paths.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636328/what-does-do-to-rubys-require-path

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU this would be a place where it might be useful :) https://github.com/soveran/cargo/issues/1#issuecomment-120707838

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, if you want to patch some built-in method, you should first make an alias for the original method. Most of the time you'll call the old one somewhere in your overriding method. Otherwise you'll lost the functionality of the original method and it's likely to break the application logic.

1. Use `ri require` or read the documentation to find out where the `require` method is defined. You'll find it's in `Kernel` module. Besides, you'll find its method signature so you know what the parameter list looks like.
2. Monkey patch module `Kernel`. **DON'T** break the functionality unless you know what you are doing.

```rb
module Kernel
  # make an alias of the original require
  alias_method :original_require, :require

  # rewrite require
  def require name
    puts name
    original_require name
  end
end

# test the new require
require 'date'
```