# How to override Kernel.load

Tags: ruby

I need to override [`Kernel.load`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load) in order to watch and process some Ruby files we've written for monitoring. However, it seems immune to such shenanigans.

It's easy to override [`require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require) and [`require_relative`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative), but `load` sits under them and bottlenecks the actual file read if I remember right.

Here's why it seems to be protected from overriding:

```
Kernel.module_eval do

  alias_method :original_require, :require
  def require(filename)
    require_result = original_require(filename)
    puts "required #{filename}"

    require_result
  end

  alias_method :original_load, :load
  def load(filename, wrap=true)
    load_result = original_load(filename, wrap)
    puts "loaded #{filename}"

    load_result
  end
end
include Kernel

require 'open-uri'
puts 'done'
```

Running that outputs:

```
required uri/rfc2396_parser
required uri/rfc3986_parser
required uri/common
required uri/common
required uri/generic
required uri/generic
required uri/ftp
required uri/generic
required uri/http
required uri/http
required uri/https
required uri/generic
required uri/ldap
required uri/ldap
required uri/ldaps
required uri/generic
required uri/mailto
required uri
required stringio
required date_core
required date
required time
required open-uri
done
```

I'm content to only override `require` and `require_relative`. However, I'm curious what's going on with `load`.

---

Afterthoughts:

It looks like `load` isn't called by `require` or `require_relative`. Mea culpa. Good catch [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt).

This question is similar to "[How to override require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661788/how-to-override-require-in-ruby)".

Good reading:

- "[Ways to load code](https://practicingruby.com/articles/ways-to-load-code)"
- "[Ruby Require VS Load VS Include VS Extend](http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/)"
- And [Jörg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) amazing answer in "[When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i/4471202#4471202)"

[Jörg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) comment

> I also want to give some love to Module#prepend, which would allow you to simply use super instead of that ugly alias_method stuff, with the additional bonus that your modifications would actually show up in the ancestry chain and thus much easier to debug.

is very sensible and worth using.

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-prepend
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-append_features

Comment: It is always interesting to see veteran SO users asking questions.

Comment: A quick look at the MRI source suggests that `require` doesn’t delegate to `load` as you suggest. They both seem to end up calling the C function [`rb_load_internal`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/load.c#L641) (at least for Ruby files, there seems to be a different path for extensions) but the `load` method isn’t on the code path for `require`. (Or have I misunderstood your question?)

Comment: I suspect you're right. I think I remember that there was a change during one of the big version updates that switched to `rb_load_internal`. Gotta go look through the errata.

Comment: @matt Digging around I don't see anything back in 1.9.3 that shows require using load. My memory is probably on the blink again. Or I need to look in Ruby 1.8. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Good candidates would be: replacing MRI with YARV (a completely different, independently developed codebase) in Ruby 1.9.0, integrating RubyGems, also in 1.9.0, and various performance improvements, bugfixes, and behavior changes since then (I remember quite vividly the fact that the version of RubyGems that was originally integrated into YARV was heavily changed from the original, and the resulting discussions that ensued on the ruby-core mailinglist. There were some problems with circular requires, exponential performance, inconsistent recognition of already loaded files, …)

Comment: I also want to give some love to `Module#prepend`, which would allow you to simply use `super` instead of that ugly `alias_method` stuff, with the additional bonus that your modifications would actually show up in the ancestry chain and thus much easier to debug.

Comment: Kudos @JörgWMittag, I'll look into your suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two simple examples that seem to work for overriding `require` and `require_relative`, based on examples in "[When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-i/4471202#4471202)".

```
module Kernel
  old_require = method(:require)
  define_method(:require) do |filename|
    puts "require #{filename}"
    old_require.call(filename)
  end

  old_require_relative = method(:require_relative)
  define_method(:require_relative) do |filename|
    puts "require_relative #{filename}"
    old_require_relative.call(filename)
  end
end
```

or

```
module KernelExtensions
  def require(filename)
    puts "require #{filename}"
    super
  end
  def require_relative(filename)
    puts "require_relative #{filename}"
    super
  end
end

class Object
  prepend KernelExtensions
end
```

Running the second using

```
module Kernel
  prepend KernelExtensions
end
```

didn't work, but since Object includes Kernel, using `class Object` overriding seems to work cleanly.

Comment: There is a nice gem that does exactly what you did in your examples: https://github.com/rubyworks/backload